# How to open links in a new tab from a PDF in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, pdf, sharepoint, hyperlink, sharepoint-2013

I have an interactive PDF that I need to host in SharePoint, it has links within it to download different documents.

The trouble is our company use Chrome and IE browser. However when you click on any of the links they will open up in the same window, not a new tab or simply download. This PDF was made in InDesign and there doesn't seem to be a logical way to do this.

There is javascript that will work in IE but not Chrome. Has anyone ever come across this?

Comment: Consider posting this question to the Super User community - Stack Overflow is intended for programming related questions

Comment: thanks shibley, ive actually managed to fix this issue!

Comment: can you add your javascript which work for IE?

Comment: you can, however Chrome doesnt read it, so what will work for one wont work for the other. the issue in my case was in Indesign i used a text box and added multiple lines of text, each with a hyperlink, IE reads this as an IMG for some reason and puts a blue box around it, i simply separated the links and bobs your uncle, problem solved.

Comment: app.launchURL("insert url here", true);